# What is the importance of reciprocal lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, microscopy

Reciprocal lattice is the diffraction plot of a crystal. Now with the STM instrument we can get the get the topology of the crystal, so what is the importance of reciprocal lattice or the Brillouin Zone?

Comment: Erm, you can get surface structure with STM, not bulk structure...

Comment: @lemon what does the Brillouin zone do then?

Comment: the reciprocal lattice is very important, for one reason at the least that we can determine a lot of properties and behaviours of the crystal from just knowing about interactions in the first few Brillouin Zones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to realize that STM is a surface technique. This means that you are probing only the surface, which can be dirty or have suffered from reconstruction, or oxidation. Moreover, it will give you rather limited statistics given the relatively small areas that you can probe.

On the other hand, x-rays probe the sample deeper and with better statistics. You also get extra information about the Structure Factor or magnetic structures if you use neutrons. If you go to inelastic x-rays/neutron scattering, you can probe for a myriad of excitations (phonons, magnons, orbitons) that are unlikely to be seen with STM. And all of this information come from techniques (x-rays and neutron) that are inherently linked to the reciprocal space.

Also, it's very helpful when you discuss delocalized states in the crystal, for example conduction electrons in a metal.

Regarding the Brilloin Zone, this is mostly a geometrical tool to better organize the reciprocal space.

Hope this clarifies a bit, and I would say that this is only the tip.

Comment: Many thanks! i'm new to it... @Ignacio Vergara Kausel

Comment: Probably I though more or less the same back then when I began my journey ;)

Comment: Will you please clarify me some what about the Brillouin Zone? @Ignacio Vergara Kausel

Comment: Thanks! Hope to get help from you in coming days @Ignacio Vergara Kausel